# How to take fields from two different table and checking the value with WHERE?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to select fields from different tables before checking the fields with WHERE clause in PHP. I understand that usually people get fields from different table like

```
SELECT t1.firstName, t2.lastName  
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE (t1.id = t2.id)
```

However, I am trying to do use the same field for WHERE clause like this:

```
$myid = $_GET['myid'];
SELECT t1.firstName, t2.lastName  
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE (t1.id = t2.id AND id = $myid)
```

What I really want is `t1.id = t2.id = $myid` for my where clause but this is giving me errors.
Below is my set of codes:

```
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT ve.vendorname, ve.vendortype, ve.rebatepercentage,
    ve.vendorimages, ve.details, vo.totalratings, vo.totalno FROM Vendors ve, vendortotalratings vo
    WHERE ve.vendorid = vo.vendorid AND vendorid = " . $vendorid);
```

Comment: Hey you are 100% right it works now

Comment: go ahead! ill pick yours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check both columns. When you `join` confirm the fields you want match then you only need to check one of the columns, because both have the same value.

```
on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id = 2
```

would match both where `t1.id` = 2 and `t2.id` = 2.

Additionally note that passing user input directly to a SQL query opens you to SQL injections. You should parameterize your query.

```
$myid = $_GET['myid'];
SELECT t1.firstName, t2.lastName  
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE (t1.id = t2.id AND id = ?)
```

then bind the `$myid`. How you bind depends on the PHP driver you are using. With PDO it can be passed directly to the `execute` as an array.

Answer (score 1):

As user @chris85 has mentioned in the comments,

```
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT ve.vendorname, ve.vendortype, ve.rebatepercentage,
    ve.vendorimages, ve.details, vo.totalratings, vo.totalno FROM Vendors ve, vendortotalratings vo
    WHERE ve.vendorid = vo.vendorid AND ve.vendorid = " . $vendorid);
```